# Managing embed segues programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, segue, uistoryboardsegue

In my app I have a sort of "dashboard" with buttons, images, labels, etc.
This dashboard is common, apart from small variations, to several view controllers.
I thought that a neat solution would be to implement the dashboard as a separate view controller that is included by means of embed segues and view containers in all the view controllers that need it.
This works perfectly.
However, I have many view controllers in my storyboard, and most of them are connected to the dashboard view controller, which makes the storyboard completely unreadable (or, at least, the connections in it).
Is it possible then to create all these connections programmatically (so that the connections go away from the SB)? It seems to be possible to create segues programmatically, but what about embed segues?
If this is not a viable solution, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Yes, and what's the question?

Comment: You're too quick :) Sorry, I hit return by mistake. I have edited my question

Comment: You could create a base view controller class that adds the dashboard controller programmatically so it wouldn't show in IB at all. Make any controllers that need the dashboard, subclasses of that one.

Comment: That's certainly possible. However, some of my view controllers are already subclasses of specific kinds of view controllers, and we don't have multiple inheritance. People often recommend against using inheritance in these cases, in the composition vs. inheritance war...

Comment: Actually: what do you mean by "add the dashboard controller programmatically"? If you mean segueing to it with a view container, that was part of my original question.

Comment: I mean, using the custom container controller api to add it (addChildViewController:, didMoveToParentViewController:, etc,).

Comment: Ok, thanks again. But the original question still stands: is it possible to create embed segues programmatically, and, if so, how?

Comment: No, you can't create any kind of segue in code -- segues are essentially storyboard visualizations of a transition between controllers. Using the custom container controller api  will accomplish the same thing as an embed segue.

Comment: I'm reconsidering your first suggestion (subclassing from a base view controller that has the dashboard). The thing that really annoys me here is that I would have to add the dashboard programmatically, and, in fact, design the entire VC programmatically, while I really need to drag/drop and move things around on the canvas in a visual way. So, is there any way to design the base view controller (including the dashboard) as a view controller on the storyboard, and subclass from it? If I do things naively, the base VC is just an unreachable (thus useless) scene. Thanks

Comment: Another way might be to create a single controller that has the dashboard as one subview, and a container view as the rest of the screen. You could design all your embedded controllers in IB, and switch out which one is embedded in the container view.

Comment: Uhmmmm, I see... but wouldn't that have exactly the same problem as the solution I adopted in the first place (dashboard embedded as a separate VC in many VCs), i.e., making the storyboard unreadable?

Comment: No, the dashboard would only be in one scene in the storyboard (the main controller that would have a container view). All the other controller would be ones that you would switch to from the original embedded controller that you get with a container view.

Comment: Forgive me for being a bit slow here, but I understand things as follow (please, correct me if I misunderstood your proposal). Consider I have N VCs that need a dashboard (N being around 30). With my solution, I would have N arcs going from each such VC to the dashboard. With your solution, I would have N arcs going from the container view to each of the N VCs. In both cases, with N around 30, I have too many arcs reaching the same point, making the storyboard pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Well, if you want to show the connections, and you have 30 controller, then you're going to need at least 30 arcs. However, with my suggestion, you wouldn't necessarily have any arcs to the controllers that you're going to switch into the container view because that switch could be done in code (although you could do it with custom segues which would then have a lot of arcs). Frankly, I'm wondering whether you really need 30 controllers -- that seems like an awful lot.